# Getting two diagonals of a Matrix

Tags: ruby, matrix

I'm using this Matrix class: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html

I'm instantiating it this way:

```
@matrix = Matrix.build(3,3) { |row, col| Cell.new }
```

How can I get the elements from both diagonals? I found I can get the elements from the upper left to the lower right diagonal this way:

```
@matrix.each(:diagonal).to_a
```

But I cant find a way to get the elements in the upper right to lower left diagonal.

Answer (score 3):

Diagonal:

```
@matrix.square? && (0...@matrix.row_size).map { |i| @matrix[i, i] }
```

Upper-right⇒lower-left diagonal:

```
@matrix.square? && (0...@matrix.row_size).map do |i|
  @matrix[i, @matrix.row_size - 1 - i]
end
```

Check for `@matrix.square?` ensures that the diagonal exists, after all.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose:

```
require 'matrix'

m = Matrix[[1,2,3],
           [4,5,6],
           [7,8,9]]
  #=> Matrix[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Obtaining the main diagonal is easy. Let's make it a `Matrix` method.

```
class Matrix
  def extract_diagonal
    each(:diagonal).to_a
  end
end

m.extract_diagonal
  # => [1, 5, 9]
```

One way of obtaining the antidiagonal<sup>1</sup> is to rotate the matrix "90 degrees" and then take the main diagonal of that matrix. To perform the rotation, here's another `Matrix` method I've found useful in various situations:

```
class Matrix
  def rotate
    Matrix[*to_a.map(&:reverse).transpose]
  end
end
```

For example:

```
m.rotate
  #=> Matrix[[3, 6, 9],
  #          [2, 5, 8],
  #          [1, 4, 7]]
```

The antidiagonal of `m` is therefore:

```
m.rotate.extract_diagonal
  #=> [3, 5, 7]
```

<sup>1. According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal), the diagonal that goes from the top left to the bottom right of a square matrix is the "main diagonal (sometimes principal diagonal, primary diagonal, leading diagonal, or major diagonal)", whereas the diagonal that goes from the top right to bottom left is the "antidiagonal (sometimes counterdiagonal, secondary diagonal, trailing diagonal or minor diagonal)".</sup>